# Is the 120 FPS video recording's quality 720P?

Tags: camera, iphone, quality

Is the quality the same as taking a normal video at 30 FPS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this lengthy review](http://philipbloom.net/2013/10/17/iphone5s/) the recording is at 720p.

The specific recording details are:

- H.264 codec
- 1280 x 720 resolution
- Millions of colours
- AAC, Mono Audio @ 44.100 kHz
- 120.15 FPS
- 29.72 mbits/s

This all matches the recording quality of a 'regular' iPhone video @ 30FPS, apart from the data rate which will vary from recording to recording.

Note that the iPhone can record 30 fps @ 1080p, [according to the apple tech specs](http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) which means that the higher frame rate is at a lower resolution.

Comment: I just made an edit there @grgarside, hopefully the answer is clearer now. 120fps recording only at 720p.